# How does the ID3 Algorithm differ from a generic Decision Tree learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, decision-problem, classification

Based on the notes of my Machine Learning lecturer, I am struggling to understand how the two algorithms differ? Both seem to select the most informative feature A (based on least entropy), then create subsets of the example set for each value of A. Then create a new branch on the tree by recursively calling ID3 on each subset.
Could someone please explain how they differ?

Comment: After thinking more about this, I'm beginning to think maybe that the decision tree itself is an abstract concept, and that ID3 is just an extension/implementation of a "decision tree". Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID3 algorithm is an algorithm for inferring a decision tree: given a training set, it tries to find a decision tree that tends to label a large fraction of the training set accurately.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm.

There is no such thing as "the generic decision tree learning algorithm".  There is no such generic algorithm.

There are many algorithms for learning a decision tree.  ID3 is probably the most well-known algorithm for decision tree learning, and the simplest, but there are other algorithms.  Other algorithms include [C4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm), [CART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics#Classification_and_regression_trees), and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning).